# Calculated column looses brackets

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, id

I have a strange problem with my calculated column.

I want to build a link utilizing the ID of the entry. So I have a formula like this:

```
="<a href='someurl.html?id="&[ID]&"'>some text</a>"
```

To have this interpreted as HTML, I changed the type to "Date and time", which is some kind of a hack, but works.

The problem is that on some time, which I wasn't able to reproduce exactly, the formula breaks. From this time the brackets [ and ] are gone, and the link will only contain "ID" instead of the current items ID.

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: I tested a little more. It seems that all existing links continue to work, but all links on new entries won't.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online or on-premise?

Comment: But even if the bracket goes, the link still works for me

Comment: 2013 on premise. Yes, the brackets are away when the field is edited again. but as long as I don't save it will work. The problem is that it will stop working at some time in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in ID column is an unreliable and unsupported column to use in a calculated column, which is why it doesn't appear in the list. If you are trying to build a field based on that column, it is best to do it via workflow. I had documented that long back in the 2007 days.

Comment: I did that, and it works. I just wasn't sure if there is another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to use the concatenate function, so SharePoint understands the string you want to return.

```
=CONCATENATE("<a href='someurl.html?id=";[ID];"'>some text</a>")
```

Comment: I tried that, but this makes no difference. Please note that your "," must be ";" or the formula won't be accepted!

Comment: Depends on the language of SharePoint ;-), but yes lets keep it to en-US